# How can I use a file (csv) from ADLS and use it as a request body for ADF web activity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to send an API request in Azure Data Factory's web activity using a csv file as my payload. I followed this [blog](https://blog.greglow.com/2023/04/29/adf-passing-a-file-attachment-via-a-post-to-a-rest-service-using-azure-data-factory/) as my initial reference but I'm getting a "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present" error. For reference, here's the pipeline that I'm currently using:

[image: ADF pipeline]

[image: Web activity settings]

[image: Web activity message]

Edit: [image: Here's my request body content]

I tried different approach aside from the one I mentioned above but it's still not working on my end.